# How to pass an undefined variable in PHP or what to do instead if I want a function to check it itself?

Tags: php

I have found numerous cases when I would like to use to output a string if a variable is defined and not empty and do nothing if it is empty or not defined.

I have achieved this this way:

```
<?php if(!(!isset($myStr) || trim($myStr)==='')) echo '<p>'.$myStr.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;?>
```

Needless to say I am willing to refactor my code and encapsulate this in a function, so I have written:

```
static function ifNotEmpty ($triggerString = '', $outputString = '') {
    if(!isset($triggerString) || trim($triggerString)==='')
        return '';
    else
        return $outputString;
}
```

And needless to say this fails (throwing "Undefined variable" error exception) if I give it (as the first argument) a name of a variable that does not exist (it is expected to be or not to be added by another class (a controller while the things happen in a view)).

I am new to dynamic languages and have never experienced such a situation (when a variable may or may not exist) before so perhaps I just lack the correct view of the things.

Comment: what you're asking for is impossible, you'll always get a warning and this `if(!(!isset($myStr) || trim($myStr)===''))` can be replaced by a simpler code: `if(isset($myStr) && trim($myStr)!='')`

Comment: Of course you can not use a variable name in context where actual _read_ access to that variable happens, when that variable doesn’t exist. You could use what PHP calls [“variable variables”](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for this, and just pass the _name_ to your method – but it is still quite unclear what your ultimate goal is. So maybe there is a better solution if you give us a more precise problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't exist you can't pass it to a function, you'll get a notice and it will exist but be `null` within the function.  Why not this:

```
if(!empty($myStr))
```

This checks for `isset()` and if it is, checks:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Comment: Does it check for all the sorts of `$myStr` emptiness including undefined, NULL, '' and ' ' (the last one is many spaces)?

Comment: No, empty checks for what the manual describes. If you want to check for “other kinds” of empty as well, then you will first have to check if the variable is set, and then check its value afterwards – f.e. for what is actually left when you remove all characters or string you consider to be “empty”.